# file scanner,file name from arguments

Tags: java

I have a code like this :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
    Scanner fc = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); 

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("vystup.txt")),true);
    String metoda;
    int pocetVrcholu;
    int pocetHran;
    String hrany;
    String pocatek;

    if(args.length == 0){   
        metoda = sc.nextLine();
        pocetVrcholu = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
    }else{
        metoda = fc.nextLine();
        pocetVrcholu = fc.nextInt();
        fc.nextLine();
    }
        grafSeznam graf = new grafSeznam(pocetVrcholu);
        for(int i = 0;i<pocetVrcholu;i++){  
            switch(metoda.charAt(0)){
                case 'M':

                    break;
                case 'S':
                    if(args.length == 0){
                        graf.pridejVrchol(i, sc.nextLine());
                    }else{
                        graf.pridejVrchol(i, fc.nextLine());
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }..........
```

Of course i cant use this code like this bcs sometimes i dont have any arguments and the program ends with error... is there a way to initialize the scanner from file like this or do i have to divide whole program to half and rewrite it(half for sc, half for fc). I tried to google, havent found any solution.... Ty for answer and sorry that names of variables arent in english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you need to validate the length of the parameters..

## Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner fc;
    if (args.length != 0) {
        fc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    } else {
        fc = new Scanner(new File("path_here"));
    }
   ....
}
```

Comment: I see, you have to declare the scanner fc outside of the if condition, i updated the answer... take a look and let me know